# is there a way to run all the tagged scenarios from a single feature file using cucumber hooks?

Tags: selenium, junit, selenium-chromedriver, cucumber, hook

i have a feature file with more than one scenario, in my cucumber hooks class i have @before which will open the browser at the beginning of every scenario, how ever every time i execute to scenarios at once, only one scenario will execute and run all the steps but the other  scenario will just open the browser but it wont actually go to the website

I would appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Update the question with `@before` hook code, `feature` file and `step definition` with error logs if any.

Comment: My Hooks  has this method:
@Before()
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario)
{ try
  {
    // get test case name getmethod
   //call the logger class
   // log the test case being executed
  // open the web browser
  }{catch{ log.info(getMessage());}}

i also have two scenarios in one feature file, one will open google.com and search for temperature . the other scenario will also open google and do the same thing but this time only  the browser will star but google wont be opened

Comment: Please update question with feature file and step definition with cucumber hooks.